# python scatter threshold function not working

Tags: python, scatter-plot

I want a scatterplot with values exceeding a particular threshold to have another color then the ones "inside" the threshold.

Here is what I wrote so far:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rnd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n  = 100
x  = rnd.uniform(low  = -1,  high = 1, size = n)
y  = rnd.uniform(low  = -1,  high = 1, size = n)

a  = x**2 + y**2
c  = np.zeros(n) 

for i in range(n):
    if a[i] <= 1:
        c[i]  = 0
    else:
        c[i]  = 1

plt.scatter(x,y, color = c)
plt.show()
```

the output is a completely black scatter plot.

```
c = array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
    1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
    0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,
    0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
    0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
    0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
    1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
    0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

I tried the following:

```
for i in range(n):
if a[i] <= 1:
    c[i]  = "r"
else:
    c[i]  = "g"
ValueError: could not convert string to float: r
```

and several other variations of the theme. However I am stuck.  Please help, thank you very much for your time.

Best wishes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have **c** defined as integers with this line:

```
c  = np.zeros(n)
```

But then in your second code snippet you are trying to set **c** as a string.

```
c[i]  = "r"
```

Choose a new name for your string array:

```
cs = []
for i in range(n):
    if a[i] <= 1:
        cs.append("r")
    else:
        cs.append("g")
```

If **scatter** complains about **c** not being from numpy, you can set a numpy chararry with: [numpy.chararray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.chararray.html).

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. It works perfect. One follow up question: is this a smart appoach, or is there something I am not aware of?

Comment: In general you have to be aware of functions that can sort an array. For example, in addition to sort(), set() will rearrange list elements. But I don't think that applies to your case.